# How to hoste multiple Django websites on single sever using NGINX and uWSGI

Tags: django, linux, nginx, hosting, uwsgi

i have a linux server running under **Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS**, i'm using **NGINX** as a web server and **uWSGI** as an application server, i have a **Django** website is already installed and running perfectly, and the exact way i did that is by following the instructions from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpR1W-NWnp4&t=2s, but the thing is that i have several websites that needs to be installed, so i tried to redo all of it for a second website on the same server, but that did not work at all.

***My question is:*** once i install a Django project exactly the way shown in the video using Nginx and uWSGI, how to install another Django project in a practical manner, in other words how to install multiple Django projects using Nginx and uWSGI.

this is my nginx server block saved at **/etc/nginx/sites-available/project_name.conf**

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/user/project_name/project_name.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    # Django media and static files
    location /media  {
        alias /home/user/project_name/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/user/project_name/static;
    }

    # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/user/project_name/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is about a 40 minutes length video. You wanted us to watch it all instead of adding your configs to your question?

Comment: well, website deployment process is a lot more than a single config file, its about a lot of things coming together to make certain website actually work, that's why i shared with you the hole thing instead of couple of files.

Comment: that being said, if there's some necessary files that need to be reviewed in order to solve the issue, please do ask and i will provide.

Comment: At first, your nginx `server` block (without private information as domain name, key/certificate filenames, etc).

Comment: i just edit my post and added your request to it

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [bash script](https://github.com/jdbit/django-auto-deploy) I wrote. It set ups as many Django websites as you want with a simple command. The script installs all the dependencies on your server, creates a virtual environment for each site, and configures a database server and Gunicorn connector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).